# (OCaml) Strange syntax used in queue.ml -- The `<-` operator

Tags: reference, ocaml, records, mutable

While browsing the Caml Light library for programming examples, I stumbled across the following code, taken from the Caml Light `queue.ml` file:

```
type 'a queue_cell =
    Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a queue_cell ref
;;

type 'a t =
  { mutable head: 'a queue_cell;
    mutable tail: 'a queue_cell }
;;

let add x = function
    { head = h; tail = Nil as t } ->    (* if tail = Nil then head = Nil *)
      let c = Cons(x, ref Nil) in
        h <- c; t <- c
  | { tail = Cons(_, ref newtail) as oldtail } ->
      let c = Cons(x, ref Nil) in
        newtail <- c; oldtail <- c
;;
```

This implementation of FIFO data structures puzzles me. I get the general idea, to keep a pointer to the last entry in the structure, so that appending at the end is possible. This makes perfect sense to me. However, it's the syntax of how this is done that bugs me.

Consider the following:

```
  | { tail = Cons(_, ref newtail) as oldtail } ->
      let c = Cons(x, ref Nil) in
        newtail <- c; oldtail <- c
```

I have a problem with types here. By the type definition, `newtail` should be of type `'a queue cell`, since it's retrieved using `Cons(_, ref newtail)` in the pattern matching: if I understand correctly, this would mean that `newtail` binds the **value** pointed by the second member of the `tail` record field (which originally is a reference).

So what does the `newtail <- c` means? If I try to replace this statement by `(fun x -> x <- c) newtail`, I get `The identifier x is not mutable.`, whereas the code sounds perfectly similar to the original variant to me.

Would rewriting these few lines to read as follows mean the same?

```
  | { tail = Cons(_, newtail) as oldtail } ->
      let c = Cons(x, ref Nil) in
        newtail := c; oldtail <- c
```

Taking the question one step further, what does the following code actually do?

```
type t = Nil | Node of (t ref);;
type box = {mutable field: t};;

let poke = function
  | {field = Node(ref n)} -> n <- Nil
  | {field = Nil} -> ()
;;

let test = {field = Node(ref (Node(ref Nil)))};;
poke test;;
test;;
```

Is it the same to write

```
{field = Node(n)} -> n := Nil
```

and

```
{field = Node(ref n)} -> n <- Nil
```

?

Even stranger: the following code returns `The value identifier a is unbound.`

```
let a = Nil;;
a <- Nil;; (* The value identifier a is unbound. *)
```

Could someone take the time to clarify the use of `<-` for me? The various examples here are pretty puzzling to me...
Thanks!

**EDIT: This was originally posted to the Caml Mailing list, but I thought the post didn't make it, so I posted it here. It appears that the posting did work; sorry for that: the link to the mailing list answer (which its original author also posted here), is https://sympa-roc.inria.fr/wws/arc/caml-list/2011-01/msg00190.html.**

Comment: I edited my answer to attempt an explanation of the error message -- I found it puzzling too. Hope it makes thing clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my answer on [the caml list](https://sympa-roc.inria.fr/wws/arc/caml-list/2011-01/msg00190.html)

Why ask the same question twice in different places ? This only leads to a duplication of efforts, with knowledgeable people wasting their time to answer you.
If you want to do that, please at least post cross-references (from your stackoverflow post to the list archive, and vice versa[1]), so that people can check that it hasn't been answered yet in the other place.

[1] yes, you can have cyclic cross-references, as the stackoverflow post is mutable!

> The semantics of mutable fields and references has changed a lot (for good) 
>   between Caml Light and Objective Caml. Beware that this code is Caml Light 
>   specific -- and if you want to learn Caml, you should rather be using 
>   Objective Caml, which is the implementation that is still maintained. 
>   In Objective Caml, only records fields are mutable. References are a derived 
>   concept, the type 'a ref is defined as :
>
> ```
> type 'a ref = { mutable contents : 'a }
> ```
>
> You change a mutable field with the syntax   foo.bar <- baz (where "bar" is 
>   a record field, and foo and baz are any expression, foo being of a record 
>   type)
>
> In Caml Light, record fields are mutable, but sum type fields (variants) are 
>   mutable as well; mutable variant fields are however not used here. See 
>   http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-caml-light/node4.6.html for 
>   documentation.
>
> In Caml Light, a record may return a mutable location, akin to a lvalue in 
>   C-like languages. For example, with the mutable variant
>
> ```
> type foo = Foo of mutable int
> ```
>
> you may write:
>
> ```
> let set_foo (f : foo) (n : int) = 
>   match f with 
>   | Foo loc -> 
>      loc <- n
> ```
>
> "foo <- bar" is used here to assign a value "bar" to a lvalue "foo" bound in 
>   a mutable pattern. 
>   In your example, two mutable patterns are used :
>
> ```
>  | { tail = Cons(_, ref newtail) as oldtail } ->
> ```
>
> - oldtail is a mutable pattern denoting the mutable "tail" field of the 
>     record
> - (ref newtail) is a specific syntax, a pattern on references. It binds a 
>     mutable pattern "newtail" corresponding to the location of the reference 
>     In other words, in Caml Light you can write the ":=" operator as such:
>
>   let prefix := r v = 
>       match r with 
>       | ref loc -> 
>         loc <- v
>
> Hope that helps.

.

**Edit:**

About the strange error message: I think that internally, Caml Light maintain a list of "value identifiers" in the scope, which come from pattern matching a mutable field (record or variant). When they see a `foo <- bar` expression, they look in that environment to find the corresponding location. Such environment is local to the expression, it never escapes. In particular at toplevel it is empty, and the errors tells you that no "value identifier" (mutable pattern) exists in the scope.

There is another thing: the namespace of value identifiers and usual identifiers are not distinct. When you match a value identifier, Caml Light adds to the scope the value identifier (mutable), but also the corresponding identifier with the matched rvalue. This can be quite confusing as you may mutate the location, but the value won't change :

```
#match ref 1 with (ref x) -> (x <- 2; x);;
- : int = 1


#match ref 1 with (ref x) as a -> (x <- 2; !a);;
- : int = 2
```

The (value) identifier will shadow any older identifier (value identifier or not)

```
#let x = 1 in let (ref x) = ref 2 in x;;
- : int = 2
```

(If you didn't know, `let pattern = e1 in e2` is equivalent to `match e1 with pattern -> e2` (except for the type system))

As the syntaxic classes for identifiers and value identifiers are the same, a non-mutable identifier will also shadow a value identifier, giving birth to a different error:

```
#let (ref x) = ref 2 in let x = 1 in x <- 3;;
Toplevel input:
>let (ref x) = ref 2 in let x = 1 in x <- 3;;
>                                    ^^^^^^
The identifier x is not mutable.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought my post hadn't been delivered to the mailing list, which is why I didn't mention it here. Sorry for that, and thanks for your excellent answer!

Comment: By the way, what about the strange error message? (just extra curiosity)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect now =) Thanks for your comprehensive and thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

In OCaml, the `<-` operator mutates mutable fields or object instance variables (references are mutated with `:=`).  However, there are other things going on like the `ref` in your pattern matching that are unfamiliar to me.  I think that it is signalling to Caml Light to match the cell as a reference (analogous to `lazy` in pattern matches in OCaml), resulting in a variable that is viable as the left-hand side of `<-` for mutation.  Passing the variable into the function passes the value of the variable, which is *not* mutable, and therefore the function cannot mutate it.

So: it looks like matching the new tail as `ref newtail` establishes `newtail` as a sugared name such that evaluating `newtail` is transformed to `!newtail'` (where `newtail'` is some internal name representing the reference itself) and `newtail <- foo` transforms to `newtail' := foo`.

I don't actually know Caml Light, though, and I am unfamiliar with this sugaring if it even exists in OCaml (the code you provided does not compile in OCaml) but that's what it looks like is happening to me.